# phonegap plugin not supported in build method

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

My mobile application in phonegap.i am using the following plugin for speech recognition

But now  phonegap is not supporting this plugin.please help to find the phonegap supported plugin for speechrecognition?

Comment: since apache cordova and Phonegap are way similar, you would try this plugin http://www.plugreg.com/plugin/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin

Comment: http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/macdonst/speechrecognitionplugin this would also be of help

Comment: i need a plugin in build method.not cli method..now i am using <gap:plugin name="com.aserputko.speech.speechrecognition2"  source="pgb" /> this plugin.but now iam trying to build my app through phone gap build and showing an error message.

Comment: try this link [here](http://devgirl.org/2016/01/08/speaking-with-cordova/)